# Persistent slug in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

In my Django web application, each user has a randomly generated token generated for purposes beyond the scope of this question.

This is the relevant `Profile` model

`models.py`

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,max_length=30)
    verified_account = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    verify_token = models.SlugField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.user.username

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('user:profile', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def generate_token(self): #important
        from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string
        self.verify_token = get_random_string(length=15)
        return self.verify_token

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs): # also important
        self.slug = slugify(self.user.username)
        self.generate_token() # issue is here
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

So basically, whenever a Profile object is created (on the creation of the User model), a token is randomly generated. However, whenever the `Profile` model is updated, so is the `verify_token`. Below is the code for my `@receiver` that handles user creation

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_or_update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    else:
        instance.profile.save()
```

I have tried to insert the following code below the `Profile.objects.create(user=instance)` line in order to try and get it to only generate the token when the `Profile` is created

```py
Profile.objects.filter(user=instance).generate_token()
```

But this gives me the following error

> 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'generate_token'

What is the best way to ensure that the slug is not changed after every update of it's `Profile` model?

Thank you in advance for any solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a slug field as read only? Also, the reason you get an error is because .filter() gives you a query set, not an instance.

```
Profile.objects.filter(user=instance).get().generate_token()
```

should work

Comment: Thank you for this - adding `editable = False` to the slug field worked. However, the code solution didn't, although that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to [Işık Kaplan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8291840/i%C5%9F%C4%B1k-kaplan) for providing the basis to my solution.

What I ended up doing was simply add a conditional to the save() function - `if self.verify_token is None:`

Thank you again!